# jQuery script not working in an iframe?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, iframe, quirks-mode

I have a page (page A) that loads the library jQuery, jQuery UI and some scripts and that page works normally.

But I have a page B, which has an iFrame that calls page A. But when I'm on page B no script into the page A runs.

This error only occurs in Internet Explorer 8 and 9, however in Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera or even when I'm on IE9 and put the page in compatibility with IE7, scripts of page A function normally within the iFrame on page B.

What could have happened?

**Edit--**
Here we go:
On page A, I have a form and it use jQuery to do validations, show Datepicker, Colopicker, to upload files. And everything works normally.

But I have to include this page A, inside page B, via iFrame. That is, on page B has to be displayed, the form of page A.

But, when I click only the "page A", validation scripts, datepicker, etc ... work normally.
But when I view this "page A" inside the iFrame on page B, it is as if the page does not loading any javascript/library. 
But this only happens in Internet Explorer 8 and 9. In other browsers, even in Internet Explorer 7, "page A" via iFrame works perfectly within the "page B".

Comment: Tell us how could you write you iframe tag. In other word give us an outline code for your two pages.

Comment: In page B, i call Page A with:
<iframe src="form_intranet.asp" width="700" height="600">

Answer (score 0):

Just close your iframe tag and test it again in Internet Explorer

```
<iframe src="form_intranet.asp" width="700" height="600"></iframe>
```

look at this resource about iframe: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Comment: A tag is closed, that is above just posted, as had configured the tag, but it is closed and it does not work well.

Comment: In this case, for Internet explorer there are some compatibility or issues in declaring the html document that may cause unexpected problems with pages. Try to check the html tag of both pages.

Comment: In other word, check out: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
does it like that or there are something extra?